# How to merge (the code of) several kernel modules together?

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I would like to know if it is possible to merge several kernel modules (device drivers, .ko files) in a single .ko file.

The code of each module (with each one's module_init()) function is available.

Hint: stand-alone modules can be compiled in the kernel. I would like to have some .ka library of modules, that could be loaded together with modprobe.

Comment: The kernel provides no built-in mechanism for doing this. I'm curious why you want to try.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: because I cannot change the loading script (which calls modprobe on a module with hard-coded name). However, I need to add some functionality (new devices). A workaround would be to create my super-module that in its module_init() function will call call_usermodehelper()/request_module() or the like to load the other modules. I wanted to know alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Merging kernel modules conflicts with the intention of dynamic (un-)loading of modules.

Comment: As would conflict compiling those in the kernel. However, it is possible to do it. I could compile all the concerned modules into the kernel, right? I am asking if it is possible to build some kind of super-module, that will handle the multiple module_init() functions at insmod() and multiple module_release() functions at rmmod(). How would that conflict with dynamic un/loading? Just a mimick of multiple insmod/rmmod calls.

Comment: This is not sufficient for an answer and should be a comment.